# Occured HibernateException in JPA

Tags: java, jpa

```
@Entity
public class ZipCode extends GenericModel {

public String zipCode;
public String townCode;
@ManyToOne(targetEntity=Town.class,fetch=LAZY)
@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="townCode",name="townCode",nullable=true,insertable=false,updatable=false)
public Town town;
}



@Entity
public class Town extends GenericModel {
public String townCode;
public String townName;
public String cityCode;
@ManyToOne(targetEntity=City.class,fetch=LAZY)
@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="cityCode",name="cityCode",nullable=true,columnDefinition="city",insertable=false,updatable=false)
public City city;
}


@Entity
public class City extends GenericModel {
public String cityCode;
public String cityName;
public String prefectureCode;
@ManyToOne(targetEntity=Prefecture.class,fetch=LAZY)
@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="prefectureCode",name="prefectureCode",nullable=true,columnDefinition="prefecture",insertable=false,updatable=false)
public Prefecture prefecture;
}


@Entity
public class Prefecture extends GenericModel {
public String prefectureCode;
public String prefectureName;
}
```

DataBase is ,

```
ZipCode

zipcode | towncode

111     | 123

222     | 456


Town

towncode | townname | citycode
123      | AAA      | 12345

456      | BBB      | 67890

789      | CCC      | 12345


City

citycode | cityname | prefecturecode

12345    | XXX      | 12

67890    | YYY      | 34


Prefecture

prefecturecode | prefecturename

12             | MMM

34             | NNN
```

and execute this,

```
List<ZipCode> zipCodes = ZipCode.find("zipcode = 111").<ZipCode>fetch();
```

and this error occured,

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found: Town[null], for class: models.Town

I try to change the DataBase value ,

Town

towncode | townname | citycode
123      | AAA      | 12345

456      | BBB      | 67890

789      | CCC      | **12321**

then, teh error has not occured...

but, I want not to change this value.
does anyone know the solution of this ?

Comment: Your mapping doesn't make any sense. You can't have a ManyToOne on a field of type List. If it's a list, it means that there are several entities, so it can be a OneToMany or a ManyToMany, but not a ManyToOne. Moreover, if you have a list of cities, the field should be named `cities`, and not `city`. This would reduce the confusion.

Comment: thanks.I edited it.but, error in not removed...

Comment: You didn't configured the ID of your entities. And the query is incorrect, since the field is named "zipCode" and not "zipcode"

Comment: @JB Nizet I think ID's are not mandatory while mapping.

Comment: Quote from http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapping-declaration-id: Mapped classes *must* declare the primary key column of the database table. Emphasis *not* mine.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try this.

```
@Entity
public class Town extends GenericModel {

    public String townCode;

    public String townName;

    public String cityCode;

}


@Entity
public class City extends GenericModel {

    public String cityCode;

    public String cityName;

    public String prefectureCode;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity=Prefecture.class,fetch=LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="prefectureCode",name="prefectureCode",nullable=true,columnDefinition="prefecture",insertable=false,updatable=false)

public Prefecture prefecture;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity=Town.class,fetch=LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="townCode",name="townCode",nullable=true,columnDefinition="city",insertable=false,updatable=false)

public List<Town> towns;

}
```